# Apache Camel: Remove specific lines from a file without checking each line

Tags: java, file, apache-camel, spring-camel

In my algorithm, I read a large file line by line (just a simple `.txt` format) and transform each line of the file into an object.

```java
@Override
    public void configure() {
        from("file:from/")
                .split(body().tokenize("\n"))
                .streaming()
                .process(handle());
    }

    private Processor handle() {
        return exchange -> {
            final String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
            // convert to DTO
            System.out.println(dto);
        };
    }
```

But the file contains the first and last lines, which should be removed. These lines start with `\\test`.
My question is: how can I delete these lines using the Apache Camel API, without check for each line for equality to this value `\\test`?
I don't want to do something like this for each file line (pseudocode):

```java
if (getFirstStringСharacter().equals("\\test") {
    removeString();
}
```

Perhaps the Apache Camel before starting to read the file can do preliminary actions and simply ignore the first and last lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The split EIP is producing (among others) two interesting exchange properties on **each** Exchange that are split:

- `CamelSplitIndex`
- `CamelSplitComplete`

Assuming the line "//test" is always present in the first and the last line, your processor (handle) could skip the processing

- when CamelSplitIndex==0 [first line]
- OR when CamelSplitComplete is true [last line]

**Example: skip first line**

```
from("...")
    .split(body().tokenize("\n"))
    .streaming()
    .filter( simple("${exchangeProperty.CamelSplitIndex} > 0") ) 
    .process( handle() );
```

Comment: Yes, thank you so much @TacheDeChoco! It's helped me to ignore the first file line.
Could you please suggest to me how can I ignore the last line? I tried many variants similar to this: ".filter(simple("${exchangeProperty.CamelSplitIndex} < ${(size() - 1)"))".

But it's not working because in fact I'm just trying to guess and can't find any documentation on working with these expressions.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your last question:

```
.filter( simple("${exchangeProperty.CamelSplitComplete} == false") )
```

In case of +/- complex condition, I recommend the use of Camel `Predicate`, eg:

```
import org.apache.camel.support.builder.PredicateBuilder;

Predicate isNotFirst = PredicateBuilder.isGreaterThan( exchangeProperty("CamelSplitIndex"), constant(0) );
Predicate isNotLast = PredicateBuilder.isNotEqualTo( exchangeProperty("CamelSplitComplete"), constant(true) );
Predicate retained = PredicateBuilder.and(isNotFirst, isNotLast);
    

from("...")
    .filter(retained)
```

Comment: Thank you again! I also came to this solution. 
I'm so glad when it's finally started work. The only sad point that I didn't find the `CamelSplitComplete` example usage in documentation myself.
Thanks, @TacheDeChoco!